How can I trigger GC.collect() in Angular (v12) when a memory threshold is reached?
I'm currently facing a memory leak issue in my Angular (v12) application, and while we're actively investigating the root cause, I'm looking for a temporary solution to mitigate its impact. I've noticed that when a certain memory threshold is reached, invoking GC.collect() manually could help alleviate the issue.
Is there a way to programmatically monitor memory usage within an Angular application and trigger GC.collect() when a specific threshold is met?
I'm open to any suggestions or best practices to handle memory management in Angular.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

GC already runs automatically, what are you exactly trying to achieve ?

manual / force to run this in the code
